# Rails, Capybara. Unable to check checkbox element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

The following is Slim.

```
.checkboxes__item
  = f.check_box :insert_thumbnail, { checked: @article.new_record? || @article.insert_thumbnail, class: 'a-toggle-checkbox' }
  = f.label :insert_thumbnail, 'insert thumbnail?'
```

HTML

```html
<input name="article[insert_thumbnail]" type="hidden" value="0">
<input class="a-toggle-checkbox" 
       type="checkbox" 
       value="1" 
       checked="checked" 
       name="article[insert_thumbnail]" 
       id="article_insert_thumbnail">
<label for="article_insert_thumbnail">insert thumbnail?</label>
</div>
```

I would like to check this checkbox in the E2E test, but it does not work.

```rb
check 'insert thumbnail?', visible: false
```

```
Error:
ArticlesTest#test_uncheck_checkbox_whether_to_display_thumbnail_in_body:
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError: element not interactable
  (Session info: headless chrome=117.0.5938.62)
    test/system/articles_test.rb:292:in `block in <class:ArticlesTest>'
```

I understand this error to mean that the element exists but cannot be manipulated.

Is this due to CSS? Or should I just pass an option other than visible to the check method?

```
.a-toggle-checkbox
  +size(0)
  display: block
  +position(fixed, left 0)
  opacity: 0
  overflow: hidden
  visibility: hidden
```

- Set the visible option to true

```rb
uncheck 'insert thumbnail?', visible: true
```

```
Error:
ArticlesTest#test_uncheck_checkbox_whether_to_display_thumbnail_in_body:
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find visible checkbox "insert thumbnail?" that is not disabled
    test/system/articles_test.rb:292:in `block in <class:ArticlesTest>'
```

- Scroll to

```rb
scroll_to 'insert thumbnail?'
uncheck 'insert thumbnail?', visible: false
```

- find + click

```rb
find('label[for=article_insert_thumbnail]').click
```

=> I can click.But I want to use `check/uncheck` method.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `But I want to use check/uncheck method.` but clicking  the label twice should toggle (check/uncheck) the checkbox

Comment: @MikeSzyndel sorry. I meaned `check` or `uncheck` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the fact that your check boxes are not visible and you are are targeting the label element with your selector, I believe you just need to enable the [`automatic_label_click`](https://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara#configure-class_method) option.

> Whether `Element#choose`, `Element#check`, `Element#uncheck` will attempt to click the associated <label> element if the checkbox/radio button are non-visible.

```
Capybara.configure do |config|
   config.automatic_label_click = true
end
```

Or pass that option explicitly to the [`check`](https://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FActions:check) method e.g.

```
check 'insert thumbnail?', allow_label_click: true
```

[Here](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/3.40.0/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb#L364) is the actual method, which has a secondary attempt if this option is true, and the error is "catchable" which it is in your case (*See below*).

This will then look for the label and call click (which seems to work for you now)

```
def _check_with_label(selector, checked, locator,
                            allow_label_click: session_options.automatic_label_click, **options)
  options[:allow_self] = true if locator.nil?
  synchronize(Capybara::Queries::BaseQuery.wait(options, session_options.default_max_wait_time)) do
    el = find(selector, locator, **options)
    el.set(checked)
  rescue StandardError => e
    raise unless allow_label_click && catch_error?(e)

    begin
      el ||= find(selector, locator, **options.merge(visible: :all))
      unless el.checked? == checked
        el.session
          .find(:label, for: el, visible: true, match: :first)
          .click(**(Hash.try_convert(allow_label_click) || {}))
      end
    rescue StandardError # swallow extra errors - raise original
      raise e
    end
  end
end
```

For Reference the "Catchable Errors" (`catch_error?(e) #=> true`) in this case would be:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementClickInterceptedError
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError 
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidArgumentError
Capybara::ElementNotFound
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped me a lot.
I actually tried it out and was able to CHECK and UNCHECK successfully.
Now I will be able to write better system tests.
Once again, thanks for your detailed explanation.